# Torch, how to use Multiple GPU for different dataset

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchvision

Assume that I have 4 different datasets and 4 GPU like below

4 dataset

```
dat0 = [np.array(...)], dat1 = [np.array(...)] , dat2 = [np.array(...)] , dat3 = [np.array(...)]
```

4 GPU

```
device = [torch.device(f'cuda:{i}') for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count())]
```

assume all the four data set have already converted into tensor and transfer to 4 different GPU.

Now, I have a function f from other module which can be used on GPU

How can I do the following at the same time,

compute 4 resulf of this

```
 ans0 = f(dat0) on device[0], ans1 = f(dat1) on device[1], ans2 = f(dat2) on device[2], ans3 = f(dat3) on device[3]
```

then move all the 4 ans back to cpu then calculate the sum

```
 ans = ans0 + ans1 + ans2 + ans3
```

Comment: Do you really plan on sending the entirety of each of your four datasets to four GPUs, in one go? Where do you plan on computing the final sum? Also - quite crucial I should say - are you planning on backpropagating from `ans`?

Comment: @Ivan for the summation part, its just a summation of four array and done on CPU. ans is the final result I need

Comment: Yes but do you need to backpropagate on it?

Comment: @Ivan Hi, I dont need the backpropagation. thank you for you answer, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Assuming*** you only need `ans` for inference. You can easily perform those operations but you will certainly need function `f` to be on all four GPUs at the same time.

Here is what I would try: duplicate `f` four times and send to each GPU. Then compute the intermediate result, sending back each result to the CPU for the final operation:

```
fns = [f.clone().to(device) for device in devices]

results = []
for fn, data in zip(fns, datasets):
    result = fn(data).detach().cpu()
    results.append(result)

ans = torch.stack(results).sum(dim=0)
```

Comment: One quesiton is that, does it the run sequentially or run at simultaneously?

Comment: I don't think it will, since its not asynchronous code. For multi-GPU usage, you might want to use [`nn.DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html)